# ROS Answers SE migration: modbus_wrapper

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I'm running on Ubuntu 14.04. I have installed the full desktop indigo distribution of ROS as in  "Installing and Configuring Your ROS environment" tutorial, also configured the ROS workspace.
I've successfully lunched roscore and several rosnodes like turtlesim.

What I try to achieve is to exchange data with a Siemens PLC using Modbus TCP.
For this I have followed the steps presented at the wikipage of ROS modbus package: http://wiki.ros.org/modbus

I have also installed the prerequisites as: https://github.com/HumaRobotics/modbus/tree/master/modbus

After restarted my PC I started a new terminal and had the following instructions:

1. **cd** to my catkin workspace
2. **source** devel/setup.bash
3. check the return of **echo** $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
4. in the same terminal I run the command to start a modbus server as stated in the above link:
   **rosrun modbus_wrapper modbus_server.py _port:=1234**

In terminal I got the following message:
**[rospack] Error: package 'modbus_wrapper' not found**

Can anyone provide a hint of what I am doing wrong?

I checked in: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages and I found pymodbus library.
I also have python 3 and 3.4 on ubuntu, none of them have pymodbus library. Is it possibile that my ROS environment not to be linked with python 2.7?

Thanks a lot!
Best regards,
Mircea.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250282/modbus_wrapper/) by [mircea.murar](https://answers.ros.org/users/28832/mircea.murar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-12-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

They have changed there modbus_wrapper package name or never had that name. Try

**rosrun modbus_cognex_insight .. .. .** or just have rosrun modbus ..... see the package names insided and also the cmakelist and package.xml you will know which one to use.

---

Originally posted by [arunavanag](https://answers.ros.org/users/29343/arunavanag/) with karma: 277 on 2017-03-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1